# Magento change menu style

Tags: magento, themes

Default menu of magneto, child items are showed in dropdown list.

I need to change them as submenu bellow main menu (as image).

[image: Sub menu bellow]

I tried to change my source code at menu block. But It complex to change and very impact to other blocks. 
Is there any other way to do?

Comment: Is the question posted for magento2 or magento 1 ? And it seems mostly to be tweak in css and structure block of magento menu

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Mageotron: It's magneto 1.9

Comment: if you want to send notification to users, you need to tag their name in comments like : @TamNguyen